# iPyKernel throwing "TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression"

Tags: python, async-await, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I know that several similar questions exist on this topic, but to my knowledge all of them concern an `async` code (wrongly) written by the user, while in my case it comes from a Python package.

I have a Jupyter notebook whose first cell is

```
! pip install numpy
! pip install pandas
```

and I want to automatically play the notebook using Papermill. No problem on my local machine (Windows 11 with Python 3.7): I install iPyKernel and Papermill and everything is fine.

The problem is when I try to do the same on my BitBucket pipeline (Python image `3-alpine`, but it happens under different others); the first cell throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
    await self.process_one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
    await dispatch(*args)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

that makes the script stop at the 2nd cell, where I `import numpy`.

If it can be relevant, I've "papermilled" under the GitLab CI without any problem in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in `ipykernel 6.9.0` - options that worked for me:

- upgrade to `6.9.1` (latest version as of 2022-02-22); e.g. via `pip install ipykernel --upgrade`
- downgrade to `6.8.0` (if upgrading messes with other dependencies you might have); e.g. via `pip install ipykernel==6.8.0`

Comment: Thank you. I've finally solved it by changing the runner image, because with Alpine I had issues with `numpy` as well, and now everything works fine.
At the same time I see that the `ipykernel 6.9.1` version came out the very same day I've asked this question, so maybe this helped too (I just install it in the runner image without specifying the version)!

Comment: @Gero actually, I got that error in a completely different context, so I think this might be useful for others as well.